# Stale reference exception for EventFiringWebDriver listener

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I  am getting Stale reference exception(Element no longer
valid),  I am using c#  - Webdriver for automation.

I am using Selenium for automation framework. In that I have used
EventFiringWebDriver class of Selenium Event. that listens to every
event of InterenetExplorerWebdriver (Like Click() or SendKeys()). In
the events of the EventFiringWebDriver class like
(ElementClicked,ElementValueChanged) I have implemented the logic that
logs the WebElementEventArgs object's attributes to XML based log
file. so at the end of the execution I can see the details of the
execution of each test case in XSLT format and track functional
errors.

code:-

```
public class SeleniumEventListener : EventFiringWebDriver
{
     public SeleniumEventListener(IWebDriver webDriver):base(webDriver)
     {
             ElementClicked += new EventHandler<WebElementEventArgs>SeleniumEventListener_ElementClicked);
//more events handled here..
 }
   void SeleniumEventListener_ElementValueChanged(object sender,WebElementEventArgs e)
 {
           LogPassedStep(e)
   }
   private LogPassedStep(e)
   {
          string title = e.Element.value;
            string status = "clicked"

         //XML based logging here.
   }
```

}

In my application which I automate using selenium. I have some text
boxes and Buttons, The EventFiringWebDriver class XMLLogging works
correctly for the textboxes through out the test case execution But
for the Buttons Or Links some of the times it Gives the "Element no
longer valid" Stale reference exception(The some buttons are of the
type Expand collapse which causes DOM to change, and In my application
I have a Task page which refreshes at regular interval in that the
Stale reference exception comes often)

The Webdriver clicks works correctly throughout the execution but the
EventFiringWebDriver fails to recognize the object and Stale reference
exception comes

Please help me.. or please suggest me the way to get that details of
the webpage objects (like button,link) so that I can implement the
Logging functionality(I am using C#-webdriver)/

Answer (score 1):

`StaleElementReferenceException` means you are accessing attribute of the element, which no longer exists.
You need to collect all needed attribute values for an element before the DOM changes.

So if you want to:

1. find element on page
2. make element disappear (e.g. open another page)
3. log that element's name

you need to:

1. find element on page
2. store element's name in the variable (`my_elements_name`)
3. make element disappear (e.g. open another page)
4. log that element's name, using `my_elements_name` variable, and not the element itself.

In python it will look like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox


browser = Firefox()
browser.get('http://google.com')

element = browser.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
element_name = element.get_attribute('name')

browser.get('http://en.wikipedia.org')

# this will raise 'StaleElementReferenceException':
print element.get_attribute('name')

# and this will work:
print element_name
# prints out: 'q'
```

Comment: That approach will increase the unneccessary code.Because for every element I deal with during the execution I will have to add the additional code.In the events of the EventListener class I had to write the XML logging logic only once.

Comment: my intention to use the EventDriver class is to Get the detailed execution report in XML format.. so do we have any other option to do it..